# XMLSEC Python on MacBook m1

Tags: python-3.x, xml, apple-m1, xmlsec, rosetta-2

Installed python lib xmlsec on macbook (M1).
When I try to run the .py program with `import xmlsec` - I get an error:

```
import xmlsec
ImportError: dlopen(/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xmlsec.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_xmlSecAddIDs
```

I tried to reinstall, and tried to use terminal by rosetta 2 also, but the result was the same

Answer (score 0):

### Use Brew:

`brew install libxmlsec1`

I created a test python file:

```
% cat xmlsec.py
def test_init(self):
    ctx = xmlsec.EncryptionContext(manager=xmlsec.KeysManager())
    del ctx
```

It passed.

For more information, check out the developer [discussing the issue](https://github.com/xmlsec/python-xmlsec/issues/163).